# Как в laravel вывести "города", которые уже привязаны к данной "области"?

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6, laravel-5.7

Подскажите, хочу списком получить города, которые приявзаны к области, которая уже привязана к стране? Как это сделать в ларавел

Мой код на view - такой

```js
<form action = "{{route('insertcity')}}" method = "post">
    <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
    @if($states)
        <label for="state_select">Select state</label>
        <select name="state_select" id="select">
            @foreach($states as $state)
                <option value="{{$state->id}}">{{$state->state_name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    @endif
    <br>
    @if($counties)
        <label for="county_select">Select county</label>
        <select name="county_select" id="select">
            @foreach($counties as $count)
                <option value="{{$count->county_id  }}">{{$count->county_name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    @endif
    <br>
        <label for="city_name">city_name</label>
        <input type='text' name='city_name' /></td>
    <label for="city_id">city_id</label>
        <input type='text' name='city_id' /></td>
    <input type = 'submit' value = "Add City"/>
</form>
```

Код в контроллере

```html
    public function index()
    {
        $states = States::all();
        $counties = Counties::all();
        return view('test.test')->with(['states' => $states, 'counties' => $counties])->render();
    }
```

**Модели**:

```
class Counties extends Model
{
  public $timestamps = false;

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id', 'county');
  }

  public function state()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\States');
  }

  public function cities()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Cities', 'county_id', 'id');
  }
}
```

```
class States extends Model
{
  public $timestamps = false;

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id', 'state');
  }

  public function counties()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Counties', 'state_id', 'id');
  }
}
```

Соответственно, пока могу выбрать только все из всех, а нужно, чтобы города были для того штата, который я только выбираю ! Как это сделать?!

Comment: `того штата, который я только выбираю` - где выбираете? Если в выпадающем списке, то лучше через AJAX слать запрос на маршрут API `states/{state}` и в контроллере в методе `show` `State::load('counties');` или как вам удобнее. Вопрос не совсем понятен: с чем возникают сложности?

Comment: Да, выбираю в выпадающем списке - сначала выбираю штат, а потом уже хочу получить все области из выпадающего списка,(которые привязанные к данному штату) из поля Select

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так.

Взял вот такой компонент:
https://select2.org (Для него есть пример интеграции во vuejs https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html )

От бэкенда нужен ответ вот в таком формате:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Россия",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Израиль",
        },
    ]
}
```

Этот компонент позволяет загружать данные при помощи Ajax.

Например, первый выпадающий список со странами будет выглядеть вот так:

```
    $("#countryList").select2({
        placeholder: "Выберите...",
        ajax: {
            url: "{{ route('country.index') }}",
            type: "get",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    title: params.term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (response) {
                let res = response.data.map(function (item) {
                    return {id: item.id, text: item.title};
                });
                return {
                    results: res
                };
            },
            cache: false
        }
    });
```

Второй список с регионами будет, например, вот таким:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "title": "Краснодарский край"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "title": "Ростовская область"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "title": "Москва"
        },
    ]
}

$("#regionList").select2({
    placeholder: "Выберите...",
    ajax: {
        url: "{{ route('regions.index') }}",
        type: "get",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            let country = $('#countryList option:selected').val();
            return {
                title: params.term,
                region: country,
            };
        },
        processResults: function (response) {
            let res = response.data.map(function (item) {
                return {id: item.id, text: item.title};
            });
            return {
                results: res
            };
        },
        cache: false
    }
});
```

Обратите внимание, что в списке с регионами мы запрашиваем регион с дополнительным параметром **country**.

Контроллеры будут выглядеть примерно вот так:

```
class CoutryController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $title = $request->input('title');
        $countries = Coutry::when($title, function ($query) use ($title){
            return $query->where('title', 'LIKE', "%$title%");
        })
        ->get();
        return CoutrySelect2Resource::collection($countries);
    }
}

class RegionController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $title = $request->input('title');
        $coutry = $request->input('coutry');

        $regions = Region::when($title, function ($query) use ($title){
            return $query->where('title', 'LIKE', "%$title%");
        })
        ->when($coutry, function ($query) use ($coutry){
            $query->whereHas('countries', function ($query) use ($coutry){
                return $query->where('countries.id', $coutry);
            });
        }
        ->get();
        return RegionSelect2Resource::collection($regions);
    }
}
```

**Это очень и очень размытое решение.**

Для того, что бы получить рабочее решение Вам понадобится понять как проверять данные из Request: 
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#form-request-validation

Как Laravel работает с CSRF
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Как работают API Resources: 
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources

Как убрать логику фильтрации из контроллера: 
https://appdividend.com/2018/05/03/how-to-create-filters-in-laravel/ 
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC3n8EP0_kK3ufmXjbpGdmIA/videos

Не использовать JQuery.